# Customize the tooltip of Chart.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'm using the last version of `vue` and `vue-chart.js`.

I'd like to customize the tooltip which is displayed when hovering a point.

#### Issue

The tooltip is not changed from the default one

#### Question

How to customize the tooltip. Ultimately I'd like to be able to click on a link in the tool tip to trigger a dialog that would display details taken from data contained in my vue component.

```
Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]

        }
      ]
    }, {
      tooltips: {
        custom: function(tooltipModel) {
                // Tooltip Element
                var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

                // Create element on first render
                if (!tooltipEl) {
                    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                    tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table></table>"
                    document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                }

                // Hide if no tooltip
                if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // Set caret Position
                tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
                } else {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
                }

                function getBody(bodyItem) {
                    return bodyItem.lines;
                }

                // Set Text
                if (tooltipModel.body) {
                    var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                    var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                        var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                        var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                        style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                        style += '; border-width: 2px';
                        var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
                        innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                // `this` will be the overall tooltip
                var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                // Display, position, and set styles for font
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._fontFamily;
                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.fontSize;
                tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._fontStyle;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            }
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    })
  }

})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooyMMG

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from html=

tooltips: {
  Add this one line = enabled:false,
        custom: function(tooltipModel)

Comment: Remove <div id =chartjs-tooltip'> from html

Comment: Please don't use the comment section for additional parts of your answer, rather edit your answer to contain all information. And, by doing so, please add some explanation such that others can learn from your answer